# Detours crashes with wglMakeCurrent

Tags: winapi, opengl, detours

I am using Detours on my project in order to save the GL Context of a Window.

So I have followed the code sample that comes with Detours 3.0 Express Edition:

```
static BOOL (WINAPI * trueWglMakeCurrent)(HDC, HGLRC) = wglMakeCurrent;
BOOL WINAPI hookedWglMakeCurrent(HDC hdc, HGLRC hglrc);

BOOL WINAPI hookedWglMakeCurrent(HDC hdc, HGLRC hglrc)
{
    wContext = hglrc;
    wDC = hdc;

    return trueWglMakeCurrent(hdc, hglrc);  //CRASH HERE
    //return TRUE;
}
```

But it crashes when invoking the original WGL method. If I change that return to `return TRUE`, it won't crash. But it obviously won't render anything either.

`hdc` and `hglrc` have valid addresses and they probably correspond to the GL Context I need, since this is called right after the desired Window creation.

**EDIT**

<strike>It does not crash when applying the same method to other OpenGL functions, e.g. SwapBuffers, glFinish, etc.</strike>

In the case of an isolated test in which I simply load my DLL and execute the `wglMakeCurrent` it works.

In the case of injecting my DLL into an application and then using `wglMakeCurrent` on this application, Detours causes an infinite recursion on the `trueWglMakeCurrent` call.

Comment: Try running it under a debugger and getting a call stack at the time of the crash. Then post the call stack here.

Comment: @MarcSherman I have tested more and found out that it is really an infinite recursion that is crashing the software. Take a look at my new Edit

Comment: My guess is that your hook is causing the infinite recursion by calling trueWglMakeCurrent. Disassembling trueWglMakeCurrent (for ex in windbg `uf trueWglMakeCurrent`) should show a JMP to hookedWglMakeCurrent as the first instruction. I believe the Detours API that installs the hook also returns a function pointer that your hook should call when it wants to call the real implementation.

Comment: trueWglMakeCurrent should be this function pointer. I solved it by placing those definitions to the same file as my DLLMain. Don't know why though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the infinite recursion that was being caused by not linking the functions properly.

Detours creates a function pointer to the original `wglMakeCurrent`, which in my case I stored in `trueWglMakeCurrent`. However it works only if I declare it and use it on the same file that has the `DLLMain` and the DetourAPI usage. Exactly like the example:

```
static BOOL (WINAPI * trueWglMakeCurrent)(HDC,HGLRC) = wglMakeCurrent;

GTNSPECTRA_C_EXPORT BOOL WINAPI hookedWglMakeCurrent(HDC hDC, HGLRC hRC)
{
    ...
    return trueWglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC);
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                   DWORD  reason,
                   LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    ...
    DetourRestoreAfterWith();

    DetourTransactionBegin();
    DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
    DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)trueWglMakeCurrent, hookedWglMakeCurrent);
    DetourTransactionCommit();

    ...
    return TRUE;
 }
```